# Import and run all modules in folder

Tags: python, python-import

Is there a way to import and run all .py files in a folder?

Basically how I think pytest does its test discovery.

It seems like I would want to import from a file path into a list and then iterate through the list calling .main(*args) on each module.

It also needs be python 2 and 3 compatible

Example

- start.py
- things/

  - mod1.py

    - main(*args):
  - mod2.py

    - main(*args):

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `importlib`. Assume the following simple directory structure:

- a.py
- b.py
- c.py

`a.py` and `b.py` contain the following simple function:

```
def main(name):
    print name
```

In `c.py` we can iterate over our directory and use `importlib.import_module` to import each file. We must ensure to make the imported modules globally accessible, otherwise they will only be local to the for loop.

`c.py`:

```
import importlib

files = ['a', 'b']

for f in files:
    globals()[f] = importlib.import_module(f)

a.main('adam')
b.main('ben')
```

Running `c.py` produces the following output:

```
adam
ben
```

Comment: Would the fact that the modules to be imported are in a sub-directory?
I chdir to the folder and try this, but get ImportError: No module named <filename>

Comment: Instead of iterating over files, use something like os.listdir() or os.walk()

Comment: To be able to do this you need to have the folder you're importing from on sys.path or it won't look there or add the current directory '.' to sys.path. Thanks a bunch!!!!

Comment: You’re welcome! If you could accept the answer so it’s helps others in the future that would be great. You could also probably just pretend the directory name to the files list if you wanted to do it that way.